# Not equal to outcome of a case statement SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SELECT query

```
SELECT bill.accountid, bill.price, bill.id, price.inclusive, price.exclusive
from bill inner join price on bill.id = price.id
where bill.price <> 
CASE bill.id WHEN 1 THEN price.Inclusive
CASE bill.id WHEN 2 THEN price.Inclusive
CASE bill.id WHEN 3 THEN price.exclusive
```

How can I achieve this where clause without separate functions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this, a `WHERE` clause with an `OR` in between the criteria for the different `bill.id` values:

```
SELECT bill.accountid, 
  bill.price, 
  bill.id, 
  price.inclusive, 
  price.exclusive
from bill 
inner join price 
  on bill.id = price.id
where 
(
  bill.id IN (1, 2)
  and bill.price <> price.Inclusive
)
OR
(
  bill.id = 3
  and bill.price <> price.exclusive
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  b.accountid, 
  b.price, 
  b.id, 
  p.inclusive, 
  p.exclusive
FROM bill b
INNER JOIN price p ON b.id = p.id
WHERE b.price <> p.Inclusive
  AND b.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the bill.id is indexed and it can be accessed effectively with condition statements,

your query cannot utilize the bill.id index because it calculated original values with bill.id.

so, my answer is, separate your result set into smaller and compare it directly.

(using or condition is also good answer. )

```sql
SELECT bill.accountid, bill.price, bill.id, price.inclusive, price.exclusive
from bill inner join price on bill.id = price.id
where bill.id in (1, 2) and bill.price <> price.Inclusive
UNION ALL
SELECT bill.accountid, bill.price, bill.id, price.inclusive, price.exclusive
from bill inner join price on bill.id = price.id
where bill.id = 3 and bill.price <> price.exclusive;
```